# How do I solve this recurrence?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

Hello guys I've spent hours on this question and am stuck. I'm not sure how to solve this recurrence.

> $$
> T(n) = \sqrt{n} \cdot T(\sqrt{n})+n\qquad \text{and} \qquad T(2)=0
> $$
> For simplicity, assume that  $n=2^{2^k}$ for some $k>0$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let $T_n=n\,U_n$ to make
$$U(n)=U\left(\sqrt{n}\right)+1$$ which is quite simple to solve

Comment: could you do it tho? I'm not sure how.

Comment: @ChrisWang. Yes, you can !